# Laravel CRUD- trying to print the contents of my JSON file

Tags: laravel

When I try to print the contents of my JSON file which has been converted in an array. I get the following error: `Object of class ... could not be converted to string.`

It does print correctly when using var_dump($array).

The `makeArray()` method works by creating a new object of my Keyboard class which extends Product.

```
$keyboard = new Keyboard ($product[id], $product[name], $product[price]);
```

How do I access this array so I can send it to display the products on the website?

Thanks.

Comment: echo json_encode($object);

Answer (score 0):

you can implement`__toStrig()`  method to class

for example

```php
class Keyword
{
  public function __toString()
 {  

     return 'bar';
 }
}

echo new Keyword(); //that line not get error because object has __toString method
```

**becarefull ,laravel return object for model  not array ,so you must use `$product->id` not `$product['id']`**